# Find value of theta in radians

Tags: geometry

In the below image why theta is calculated as below? Mainly I want to why it is negative? I don't get that part.

> $$-\dfrac{3\pi}{2} - \dfrac{\pi}{4}= -\dfrac{7\pi}{4}$$

[image: Image-B]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each full quadrant of revolution is $\frac{\pi}{2}$. Going from the positive y-axis to the positive x-axis is one quadrant, to the negative y-axis is two quadrants, and to the negative x-axis is three quadrants, giving us $\frac{3 \pi}{2}$. Then the final part of the angle is stated to be $\frac{\pi}{4}$, so the total angle is $\frac{3 \pi}{2} + \frac{\pi}{4} = \frac{7 \pi}{4}$, then we apply the minus sign because it's a clockwise angle which we are defining to be the negative direction for angles.

Comment: Does it mean that if we clockwise -ve sign is applied and if we go counter clockwise +ve sign is applied ?

Comment: Yes. You have to pick a direction to be positive (so that you can do things like add angles easily), and the convention is for counter-clockwise to be positive.

Answer (score 0):

Each quadrant represents $\pi/2$, and since it is clockwise direction, then in total the 3 quadrants represent $-\pi/2 * 3=-3\pi/2$. Finally, there is still a $-\pi/4$, so the result is $-3\pi/2-\pi/4=-7\pi/4$